# Polygon.io: get the industry and sector for a ticker

Tags: python, polygon.io

I'm new to using the polygon.io api polygon. I've figured out most of what I need but I am stumped at retrieving sector and industry for a ticker. There are examples on the web of using get_ticker_details, but I can not repeat their result. Even if I use the demo on polygon.io's website it doesn't return industry and sector. Any and all suggestions would be welcome. Thanks

I tried the following

```
client = Utils.getClient(api key)

tmp1 = client.get_ticker_details('AA')
tmp2 = client.get_ticker_details('AAPL')
```

These called returned a wealth of data but that did not include industry and sector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ticker Details Endpoint returns the Standard Industrial Classification (SIC) code for each ticker. These codes can be mapped to their definition/sector from the [SEC's sic code list](https://www.sec.gov/corpfin/division-of-corporation-finance-standard-industrial-classification-sic-code-list).

Comment: Thank you so very much. I can't believe it was staring me in the face and I didn't recognize it. I presume that sector is not part of the data.

Comment: Happy to help! 

Please feel free to reach out to us by email at support@polygon.io if you have any further questions!